# Power Series Solution to Non-Linear Partial Differential Equations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am looking for power series solution methods  used to solve Linear partial  Differential equations , mathematica doing verywell for a single ODE using asymtoticDSolve , maple it is capable to find a power series solution as $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } y^j x^k c(k,j)$$
I try to put an example heat equation with initial conditions as
[image]
it is possible to do the same in Mathematica??
my first question is possible to find a command  pde/solve as maple in Mathematica for two variables as above??
and I try to get part of a matrix as

[image]
the result it is must be one element c[0,0]  how I could solve thanks anyway

Comment: "is possible to find a command pde/solve as maple in Mathematica for two variables as above?? "  You forgot to show the PDE you are trying to solve and what commands you used. is it a PDE or ODE you wan to solve using power series?

Comment: In case someone wants to try this in Maple, here is the code `pde:=diff(u(x,t),t$2)=diff(u(x,t),x);ic:=u(x,0)=cos(x),D[2](u)(x,0)=sin(x);pdsolve([pde,ic],u(x,t),'series',order=4);`  I could not get Mathematica's `AsymptoticDSolveValue` to do this for the heat pde. I do not think it supports pde's, only ode's.  screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOOpY.png)    btw, there is nothing non-linear about this pde. So not sure why OP calls it nonlinear.

Comment: Another way: `SOL = DSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] - D[u[x, t], x] == 0, 
   u[x, 0] == Cos[x], Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == Sin[x]}, 
  u[x, t], {x, t}]; 
SOL[[1, 1, 1]] -> 
   Series[SOL[[1, 1, 2]] // Re // ComplexExpand, {x, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 
     3}] // Normal // Expand` ?

Comment: Thanks @Mariusz Iwaniuk works great but the above method  have a inconvenient you must calculate first the close form solution

Comment: Thanks @Nasser for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult, at least for me, to help with the first part of the OP without a specific example.

For the second part, though, the problem you have is due to the `MatrixForm`; see below:

Firstly, I am using

```
"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"
```

We have

```
Sum[c[k, j] x^k y^j, {k, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}]
```

which gives the output

> 

```
c[0, 0] + y c[0, 1] + y^2 c[0, 2] + y^3 c[0, 3] + x c[1, 0] + 
 x y c[1, 1] + x y^2 c[1, 2] + x y^3 c[1, 3] + x^2 c[2, 0] + 
 x^2 y c[2, 1] + x^2 y^2 c[2, 2] + x^2 y^3 c[2, 3] + x^3 c[3, 0] + 
 x^3 y c[3, 1] + x^3 y^2 c[3, 2] + x^3 y^3 c[3, 3]
```

Then we ask for the list of coefficients

```
g = CoefficientList[
  Sum[c[k, j] x^k y^j, {k, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {x, y}]
```

which returns

> 

```
{{c[0, 0], c[0, 1], c[0, 2], c[0, 3]}, {c[1, 0], c[1, 1], c[1, 2], 
  c[1, 3]}, {c[2, 0], c[2, 1], c[2, 2], c[2, 3]}, {c[3, 0], c[3, 1], 
  c[3, 2], c[3, 3]}}
```

Then we can use `Part` in the following way

```
g[[1]]
```

to get

> `{c[0, 0], c[0, 1], c[0, 2], c[0, 3]}`

or we can use

```
g[[1, 1]]
```

which returns precisely one element as it should

> `c[0, 0]`